# Be notified when debounceTime has elapsed from an Observable

Tags: angular, observable, behaviorsubject

Say I am provided with an Observable on a Subject like below:

```
private subject: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
public observer: Observable<any>;
constructor() {
    this.observer = this.subject.debounceTime(300).switchMap(// do something);
}
```

and then in my code I have

```
otherComponent.observer.subscribe(// obtain new value);
```

I know that subscribing to this observer, I will get the new value once it's subject's value is changed (i.e. after "do something returns"). I wonder if I can know, via this observer, that the debounceTime 300ms has ended/the process to start changing the value is started (i.e. before "do something starts").

If not, how to you achieve the same effect (e.g. via changing another Subject as Observable before "do something" inside switchMap())?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a side effect:

```
this.subject.debounceTime(300)
  .do(value => /* Do something */)
  .switchMap(// do something);
```

Or in newer version of rxjs when using lettable operators, `do` has been renamed to `tap`.

Comment: Thanks, but what would you do inside the ".do()" to notify another component? change another Subject? emit an event?

Comment: That's up to you and depends on what it is you are trying to do, specifically. You can also call a method on some service, emit on a subject, … It really depends on what side effect you are trying to achieve. There's no »template« answer.

Comment: Alright. If you don't mind answering this too: I tried adding ".do()" after ".switchMap()" and the code inside only runs after the inner Observable of switchMap finishes, is this expected?

Comment: If by finish you mean emits, yes. If you mean completes, then no.